# What time format is this guy's "watch"?

Tags: in-time

I'm watching [In Time (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637688/), and at the beginning of the film, in the bar, there is a guy who has the following watch on his arm:

[image]

The watch shows

```
0116:39:3:23:58:38
```

So, this should mean 116 years, 39 months, 3 days, 23 hours, 58 minutes, and 38 seconds. I am confused about the **months** part. Shouldn't it be **11** at maximum? Why is it greater than 11 in the watch?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe they aren't using months at all. It could be 116 years, 39 weeks, 3 days, 23 hours, 58 minutes and 38 seconds.

Answer (score 39):

If you go to the movie's [official website](http://www.intimemovie.com/), there are screens that show what the time format is. See the attached image. The format is **Years - Weeks - Days - Hours - Minutes - Seconds**.

[image: In Time Date Format]

Answer (score 1):

**Years - Weeks - Days - Hours - Minutes - Seconds.**

*This makes sense cause not every **Month** has the same amount of **Days** in it.
How would you know if it is a 28 day month or a 31 day month?